# Extending Laravel 4 connection class?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way to extend the Laravel connection class?

Basically I need the power of the `insert()` command, but I need a few more words added to the query. Laravel doesn't have an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` function. So I need to be able to pass my array of data into the function, and have it take care of the rest.

I tried a raw query, but I don't really know what to do to make my multidimentional array of data work with the SQL, Laravel seems to do it like magic.

I want to have something like:

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

And in the Laravel insert function, which is this:

```
public function insert($tableName, array $data, array $types = array())
{
    $this->connect();

    if (empty($data)) {
        return $this->executeUpdate('INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' ()' . ' VALUES ()');
    }

    return $this->executeUpdate(
        'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . implode(', ', array_keys($data)) . ')' .
        ' VALUES (' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '?')) . ')',
        array_values($data),
        is_int(key($types)) ? $types : $this->extractTypeValues($data, $types)
    );
}
```

Have this instead:

```
public function insertIgnoreDuplicates($tableName, array $data, array $types = array(), $col)
{
    $this->connect();

    if (empty($data)) {
        return $this->executeUpdate('INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' ()' . ' VALUES ()');
    }

    return $this->executeUpdate(
        'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (' . implode(', ', array_keys($data)) . ')' .
        ' VALUES (' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '?')) . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY SET $col=$col',
        array_values($data),
        is_int(key($types)) ? $types : $this->extractTypeValues($data, $types)
    );
}
```

I saw a couple of blogs on extending the class, but they say the only way to do so is to reimplement each function, which is bad when it comes to Laravel upgrades.

Unless someone has a different option to do a:

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

And add the duplicate key constraint, I would love to hear.

I've tried this:

```
$columns = implode(", ", array_keys($data));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($data));
$values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
if (DB::statement("INSERT INTO `my_table` ($columns) VALUES ($values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_a = col_a")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Which I found on another SO post, but I keep getting "mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

So any help is appreciated. I really wish Laravel had this default functionality because all of the behind the scenes work really makes things easier to accomplish.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused by some member of the `$data` array; `mysql_real_escape_string` expects a string, and the `array_map` is feeding every member of `$data` to it, regardless of type.

There's no need to manually escape values before passing them to `DB::statement`. Eloquent uses PDO behind the scenes, which will escape bound parameters. Try something like `DB::statement('INSERT INTO`my_table`(?, ?) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_a = col_a', array('col_a', 'col_b', $data[0], $data[1])`

Comment: Is there anyway for me to pass $data as an array instead of specifying indexes? It's multi dimentional, Each has the same keys with different values. So 1 insert statement for an array of 500 instead of 500 insert statements.

Comment: You can pass multiple tuples into the `VALUES` clause, e.g., `INSERT INTO table (?, ?) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),`...etc...`(?,?), array ('col_a', 'col_b', $data[0]['col_a'], $data[0]['col_b'], $data[1]['col_a], `... and so on.